# Transition rate of incoherent perturbations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, radiation, perturbation-theory

The following is an excerpt from Griffiths book "Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd Edition, page 353-354", where he derives *the transition rate* of a two level state under the influence of range of electric fields jumping from quantum state $\psi_b$ to $\psi_a$

[image]
[image]

**Questions:**

- How is $\hat{k} \perp \hat{n}$ maintained by integrating over all of $\theta$ and $\phi$?
- Where does the factor $\frac{1}{4 \pi}$ come from and why is $\mathcal{p}$ still given as a vector inside the integral, does the first equation of (9.46) not follow from $$|\mathcal{p} \cdot \hat{n}|^2_{avg} = \int |\mathcal{p} \cos \theta|^2 \sin \theta d \theta d \phi?$$

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Please type the relevant parts of the problem instead of using an image. This is important for several reasons. Typing out the relevant parts 1) Makes it easier to read, 2) Makes the text searchable, 3) Makes the text editable, 4) Forces you to focus on the parts that actually matter.

Comment: @DanielSank Yeah I know, I usually do, but it's hard if the question is at the end of a section, hence there is a lot of context that needs to be given. The actual text might help with the question in the event I omit something vital.